# Showing images in markdown for gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I am following the [Working with images in markdown posts and pages](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/)  tutorial for gatsby and installed the following plugins

- gatsby-image
- gatsby-transformer-sharp
- gatsby-plugin-sharp

My images are in the same directory as my Markdown files in src/content. But my posts are still without images. I suspect I have to change something in my src/templates/blog-post.js to show the images but am unsure of the next step. Can someone tell me what changes I need to make?

[Github](https://github.com/develijahlee/yonseiuicscribe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to embed images in markdown you also need `gatsby-remark-images`. Run `yarn add gatsby-remark-images` or `npm install --save gatsby-remark-images`.

Add this to your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 590,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```